# CGI-Bin does not seem to be set up

Tags: server

I've used tasksel and installed LAMP server.
But I can't seem to figure if Cgi-bin is set up.
There is no Cgi-bin in the web root folder.
And when I try and call a test.py file from the browser, it downloads it rather than
executes it.

I've had a look at various how-to's but i'm still no closer.

Ubuntu 14.04
Apache 2.4.7 (Apr 3 2014)

Comment: Could you add information about apache version and ubuntu version?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#scriptalias)

> The ScriptAlias directive has the same behavior as the Alias
>   directive, except that in addition it marks the target directory as
>   containing CGI scripts that will be processed by mod_cgi's cgi-script
>   handler. URLs with a case-sensitive (%-decoded) path beginning with
>   URL-path will be mapped to scripts beginning with the second argument,
>   which is a full pathname in the local filesystem.

The **ScriptAlias** directive looks like:

```
   ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/
```

It means that if you Request URL `http://mydomain/cgi-bin/myscript.py` Apache tries to run `/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/myscript.py`

> The ScriptAlias directive tells Apache that a particular directory is
>   set aside for CGI programs. Apache will assume that every file in this
>   directory is a CGI program, and will attempt to execute it, when that
>   particular resource is requested by a client.

**ScriptAlias** directive is in default `apache2.conf` configuration file and it works if **[mod_cgi](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_cgi.html)** is enabled and `myscript.py` is executable and return proper output.

If you have a different configuration, you should read: [Apache Tutorial: Dynamic Content with CGI](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/cgi.html)